# If a male can be a 'stud', what is the corresponding word for a female?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Is there anything equivalent on the female side of the gender? Traditionally, the qualities connotated to a *stud* were positively charged when talking about males but had a great portion of negative touch when it came to females.

However, as the world changes and our culture (d)evolves, I wonder if there's a corresponding term to being *a stud* but such that it can be applied to a woman.

Comment: Could you please explain what parts of the definition of "stud" you want to apply to women? The word usually paired with *stud* is *babe* but it doesn't necessarily have the same physical implications.

Comment: maybe *maneater* http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=maneater

Comment: @Jim Not being NSE, I can't be certain but in my ears, the term *maneater* has a negative, although not derogatory, implication.

Comment: The word that comes to mind is "bombshell".

Comment: *Stud* also has a negative, although not derogatory implication- depending on who's using it.  Between guy friends a *stud* may be a badge of honor.  Between woman who've gotten suckered in it could be derogatory.  Between guys discussing women they're interested in, the statement, "stay away from her she's a maneater" might not be complimentary, but between women friends, "I wish I could just be a maneater like you" might be a positive thing.

Comment: @Catija I'm not entirely sure that I have a clear understanding of how the behavioral pattern of someone called *a stud* relates to the cultural aspect (since being one is or, at least, has been regarded as truly desirable). Hence, I can't answer your question. However, the suggestion you've made seems to me spot on suitable. Post it as a reply, please.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Might be my dirty mind but I'm picturing a very chesty, curvy bimbo... But that **might** be slightly what one should picture when a *stud* is mentioned. In such case, it'd mean that the term's started to deteriorate in attractiveness... Interesting.

Comment: Remember that *stud* derives from animal breeding practices where a desirable male is farmed out to impregnate many different females.  Calling a guy a stud compares their breeding habits to those of the desirable stud animal: "frequent, with many partners and with no commitment."

Comment: That was not my intention. Bombshell does not have any bimbo-ey connotations for me, nor does stud have any negative connotations. I think it's also worth noting that "stud"doesn't have to be purely about physical looks, it can easily mean "a cool guy"

Comment: @Jim I just realized that it's kind of obvious that it's the sexual conduct that's implied by the reference to a horsie that gets a lot of ass. However, I've been (probably wrongly) always thinking that *a stud* was a guy who's appearance exhibits the best qualities (e.g. perfect jaw, desirable shoulder width, firmness of sitting device etc.). Because that's what the aforementioned horsie should look like in order to be allowed to spread the great genes. But You're most likely more right - it's about sleeping around...

Comment: @Konrad - The word _stud_ can be used in both ways. Perhaps  you should edit your question and explicitly state which sense of the word you are concerned about.

Comment: It's just *horse*.  *Horsie* is what five-year-olds call them.

Comment: @Catija Oh, I know, I know. I was being stylistically creative by using a diminutive form of *a horse* to create a contrast versus the more adult and borderline vulgar *to get ass*. Good point, though, because some beginner might get it wrongly.

Comment: I haven't read all the comments above, but the mentioning of *horsie* makes me think of *horsey* and *horsy*, and then *hottie*.

Comment: *Correspondant* is not an English word. Also, it remains unclear what you mean by *Traditionally, the qualities connotated to a stud were positively charged when talking about males but had a great portion of negative touch when it came to females*.

Comment: @δοῦλος Weird... I elaborated on the subject but it seems like my comments disappeared... And it looks like if your comment came 52 minutes ago. But it was yesterday, wasn't it...?!

Comment: @KonradViltersten "Get it wrong" is the proper phrasing.

Comment: @snailboat Huh? I have no idea what you're referring to. Please elaborate.

Comment: I agree with "babe." But if you want another animal-related one, how about "a fox"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>I have used bold to highlight the important parts that I think need to be in the female word - so we can see they are describing the same thing.</sup>

*"Stud"* now has many meanings, which makes this harder to answer. I will try to cover them all.

UD says:

> Stud (Urban Dictionary):
>   This person is **really cool**. Everyone **looks up to them** and wants to **get with** them.

<sup>Get with means to **kiss** or **take part in touching**, referring to two people who are **not dating** or have **just started** dating</sup>

This means that they are likely to often *not* be in a relationship, otherwise they wouldn't be as available as it implies, which suggests someone popular, perhaps has had a large number of transient sexual relationships.

> Stud (Google Define):
>   a young man thought to be **very active sexually** or regarded as a **good sexual partner**.

So, as Urban Dictionary said someone promiscuous, popular and likely to be sporty, which leads me onto another (American) word:

> Jock (Wikipedia):
>   ...a jock is muscular, but **not very smart**, and cannot carry a conversation on any topic other than one relating to sports, exercise, or **sex**.

So again, sex is coming up here.

I am not including the [Google Images (NSFW)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=male%20stud&es_sm=122&biw=1920&bih=953&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=PHcYVebuOo31aKrDgBA&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ) "definition" here because that is more focused on the "publicly perceived definition" of looks, rather than the real one (promiscuity). The two are (closely) linked but I don't want to complicate the matter further.

This leads me to a few words for females that apply:

> Bimbo (Google Define):
>   An **attractive** but **empty-headed** young woman, especially one perceived as a **willing sex object**.
>
> Funnily enough, [this used to be a word for a male](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimbo), back in the 1920s, when it first appeared in AmE.

This has the lack of intelligence and the sexual promiscuity of *"jock"* but doesn't really have the popularity of a *"stud"*.

> Bombshell (Google Dictionary):
>   a **very attractive** [often blonde] woman.

This also lacks the popularity part, something that no word for females seems to include. Both are focusing on the looks of the female, which is something I said I was avoiding earlier in this answer (the perceived definition, or Google Images definition).

However, I think it is *implied* by the terms above (as well as other words used to describe a promiscuous person), and therefore would suggest you use the word *"Bimbo"* (with caution, the *"willing sex object"* part isn't an especially flattering way to describe someone).

Have a look at the [Urban Dictionary for Popular Girls](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=popular%20girls), it may shows what I mean.

Answer (score 10):

A **babe**.

A *stud* is a male whose exudes his sexuality in one way or another.

A formal [definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stud)  is 'a man who is notably virile and sexually active'. An informal definition is 'a man that makes women drool'.

A *babe* is a corresponding [word](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Babe)  for a female. As in

Gina Bellman is such a babe.

Answer (score 2):

The term closest to the female version of stud to me is **"vixen"**  I rarely hear it used currently, though it's quite common in older films.  In British English, "minx" seems appropriate as well, though does not seem to connote attractiveness as much as does vixen.

It's a bit unclear, but I am surmising that you are defining stud as: "an attractive male with sexual prowess"

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the term you are looking for, but for completeness' sake:

### Broodmare

In the most literal sense, the female equivalent of a *Stud* is a *Broodmare*  (at least in the equine realm.)

A *stud horse* is a stallion kept for breeding, who is believed to have all the desired qualities for siring desirable offspring.

Similarly, a *broodmare* is a mare who runs no races and pulls no plows - she just bears young over and over.

The connotation if used on a person would not be equivalent, however.  A human *stud* is a handsome, athletic male with at least decent social skills.  A stud need not have children - he only has to have good traits that could be passed on.  *Stud* definitely has positive connotations.

*Broodmare* isn't as frequently used for people, but if I heard it, I would assume that the speaker was commenting on a woman having little else happening in her life other than raising children, possibly with multiple fathers.  A broodmare must have children.  It is hard to imagine *Broodmare* being meant as a compliment.

Comment: "Broodmare is not likely to be a compliment." That is putting it mildly.  I think most people would consider that applying this word to a human woman would be quite offensive, and the speaker might well be seen as sexist or misogynist.

Comment: @NateEldredge  Strengthened that statement.