# Is there any word that describes male equivalent of bimbo?

Tags: vocabulary, synonyms

Dictionary meaning of bimbo seems to be 'an attractive but unintelligent or frivolous young woman'. So the question is if there is an equivalent term for 'an attractive/handsome but unintelligent or frivolous young man'?

Comment: Related: [If a male can be a 'stud', what is the corresponding word for a female?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/53743/9161)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen the invented word "himbo" used for that.
[Wikipedia "himbo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himbo)

Wikipedia also offers a few synonyms: bimboy, mimbo, boy toy and Blank Chuck.

Of those possibilities, I think "boy toy" has some currency.

Answer (score 0):

Bimbo was originally an Italian slang word for a dumb brutish man in fact, it didn't start to mean dumb pretty women until English Americans adopted it.

Comment: Welcome to [ell.se]! You might want to [edit] your answer to support it with some [references](/help/referencing).

Comment: There are many loan words in English that don't have exactly the same meaning as they do in the language they were borrowed from. While this is an interesting bit of information, I don't think it answers the question. Regardless, the Italian isn't the singular source of the word in English. See https://www.etymonline.com/word/bimbo

Answer (score -1):

I have a list of some English slang.

Jock, meat head, ogre, oaf, stud (a horse used to breed with)?

Here is some more I think

http://onlineslangdictionary.com/thesaurus/words+meaning+attractive+male.html